# How to generate hard-coded latex (insert bibtex and references)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing

I have written a paper in LaTeX using Bibtex for my citations (I use `\citep{}` and `\citet{}` in the text) and of course referencing tables, equations and figures using `\ref{}`.

Unfortunately the journal requires that LaTeX submissions be hard-coded and not use Bibtex.  So to submit I would have to find every `\ref` or `\citep` and insert the text that I see in the .pdf file into a copy of the original .tex file. For example, instead of `\citet{Smith2006}` I would have to type in `"Smith, 2006"` all over the place. Similarly I'd have to figure out what all the equation and table numbers and insert them by hand. I will also need to include the bibliography as straight LaTeX. I can do this pretty easily by editing and inserting the .bbl file, so I'm most worried about the citation and references part.

Is there some way to generate an intermediate file automatically, like a LaTeX preprocessor or something that inserts all the bibliography citations, table references, equation references, etc. and generates a hard-coded LaTeX file?   I can't seem to find a solution even though it seems like a problem lots of people must face.

I don't understand why the journal requires this hard-coding, but let's just take it as a given and see if we can find a solution.

Edit: Thanks for the info about including the .bbl file.  I do that, which is good but apparently it's not enough.  The journal wants actual text:  "table 5", "equation 10.2", and "Jones et. al, 1995" in the text rather than \ref and \cite commands. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @farns With "hard-code" you mean that the `.tex` file mus be self-consistent?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Make sure you complain enough to the journal editors. In these times, the journal's behavior is simply unacceptable and simply unscientific.

Comment: Which one is it? I'll write them and tell them to GTFO.

Answer (score 7):

After having run bibtex you will have a `.bbl` just replace the `\bibliography` command by the contents of this file.  There is no need to change `\cite` or `\ref` commands in the document.

Answer (score 4):

If they need (1) only one file submitted and (2) only one LaTeX pass needed, then you can do the following:

Do several passes of `latex` so that all cross-references are resolved correctly. Then open the `.aux` file and copy its contents *just before `\begin{document}`*. This should be satisfactory for everything to work.